# Site like Stack Overflow but with blog posts / articles

Tags: discussion

Hello there!

We all know digg, right? Digg is awesome website, there are bunch of interesting
articles and you can vote them up and down, and you can quickly access great articles
about whatever you are interested in.

The only problem with Digg is that is not that much interesting for us -- programmers.

I just thought it would be great to have a website, like Digg, but with artiles only
about programming.

There are so many awesome blogs online! So many .. But we can't read it all, and we
can't either find all the great articles. So why not share it?

Here, let me illustrate what I mean

Mere Mortal          ->     Progammer

Yahoo Answers        ->     Stack Overflow

Digg                 ->     ???

So I'm wondering if anyone knows a site like this and if not, then just write here
what you think about this.

Thanks

Comment: i fail to see how this is related to the SOFU trilogy.  perhaps this is something you should be asking on Yahoo Answers?

Comment: Yeah, that's just what we need.. to blend SO with digg. </sarcasm>

Answer (score 3):

[Code project](http://www.codeproject.com) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You almost lost me at "Digg is awesome..." but I kept reading.  ;)

Reddit has "subreddits" that serve a similar purpose to tags.  Try these:

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/
http://www.reddit.com/r/coding

Answer (score 1):

Hacker News? http://news.ycombinator.com/

Comment: No tags. That's bad.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [DotNetKicks](http://dotnetkicks.com/)? It doesn't host the content, but links to it. Links can be kicked or drop-kicked, and these is the ability for comments on links.